# link image symfony

Tags: php, css, .htaccess, symfony1, symfony-1.4

I have small problem with website developped using Symfony 1.4,the problem is the link of image in views templates and also in css on OVH server dosn't work.

for example the link "/images/logo.png" works very fine in a remote server (plesk) and on my local machine too but in OVH Server no logo displaying... that give me

```
failed to load the given URL
```

And just on OVH server?!

Edit :

in firebug when I change /images/logo.png to ../images/logo.png,so the link of image works very fine!!

Edit 1 :

you don't understand, I have a lot of images are with this link /images/...,so I must change all links??!!Can you know any method to change just on configuration or htaccess to redirect it directly to folder images?

Comment: Try using an absolute link: `/home/username/public_html/images/logo.png`

Comment: you don't understand, I have a lot of images is with this link /images/...,so I must change all links??!!Can you know any method to change just on configuration or htaccess?

Comment: You can use `.htaccess`: `RewriteRule ^(.*)/images/$(.*) http://www.yourdomain.com/path/to/images/$2 [L,R=301]`

Comment: sorry that not work!!

Comment: @Titanium - using abolute paths is never a good option, and adding them to your webpage is even worse (despite the fact that it simply won't work).
@NII - use Fiddler or similar tool to check whether the URLs are generated correctly. If yes you have to check your htaccess or servers configuration as it may be redirecting the requests.
Also - you can try @Titanium's Rule but the `$` sign should be at the end: `^(.*)/images/(.*)$`

Comment: @MichalTrojanowski - You're right, I missed that last `$` sign.  And yes, I'm not a big fan of absolute paths however, they will work if they're used correctly.